# git commit shows a commit(a tex file) has 3054 lines added and 2996 lines removed, but use GUI tools showns only 60 lines added

Tags: git, eol

I'm using git under Windows, I use TortoiseGit or GetExtension as a GUI client.

I see a commit which changes a `.tex`, and from the GUI, I see 3054 lines added and 2996 lines removed.

[image]

But when I use the diff GUI tool, it only shows about 60 lines at the file.

[image]

So, is there any wrong with the commit?

I checked the EOL of this file, it's not changed.

Comment: Perhaps there are lots of whitespace-only changes, and the GUI disregards them?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I have already enabled the "compare white space" option in the GUI diff tool, and I don't see the difference. So, this is not caused by the whitespace removes.

Comment: You say you checked the EOL, but I have a hard time believing that this is not a LF vs CRLF issue. Your lines removed count is the whole file, that's very suspicious. Do you have any ignore-whitespace setting enabled in your diff GUI tool? And what you're autocrlf set to?  I.e., what does `git config --get core.autocrlf` output? I would not be surprised if a Windows diff GUI tool ignored differences in newlines by default, by the way.

Comment: I bet it's an EOL format change problem.

Comment: It's virtually guaranteed to be an end-of-line (LF vs CRLF) change. These are very hard to see in viewers, which generally look at the files *after* the line endings have been resolved to match; the internal storage inside the repository (of the compressed and de-duplicated files) uses the files *before* line endings have been resolved to match.

Comment: When I run `$ git config --get core.autocrlf`, I got the return value `true`. So, I guess internally git will save the `.tex` file in `LF` format, but when I check out the file in my working dir, it is in `CRLF` format. I originally guess it is an EOL related issue, but I can't check what EOL file format does git internally save for the `.tex` file.

Comment: I have followed [this github page](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings), in the `Windows` page, I follow the steps, I first add a `.gitattributes` file, and mark the `.tex` file as `text` file, and later I run the `git add --renormalize .` command, and after that, I noticed that there are 2 `.tex` file which are changed and need to be updated including the one in my question. This means those 2 files were saved in `CRLF` format in the repo. Now I fixed them, I'm still not sure why those 2 files were mistakenly saved by git.